# git push: when does it create the dst?

Tags: git, push

It's not clear to me under which conditions a remote `<dst>` will be created or not. Assuming origin is going to a remote, in 
`$git push origin localBranch:newRemoteBranch`
newRemoteBranch will be created if not existing.
But when I use the syntax where `<src>` is the sha1 hash of an arbitrary commit, seems like the push will only succeed if the remote branch exists prior to pushing. 
Is there a way to create the remote branch from an arbitrary commit other than being forced to use an existing ref for `<src>`?

Comment: Perhaps you can say what it is that you're _really_ trying to do. Because I suspect that you're going about it in not quite the best way, so your question doesn't make a lot of sense. And even if you do get an answer that "works", I suspect it will lead you do do things that are not recommended practice.

Comment: I wasn't detailed and thorough in my question, but tbh I was assuming that who knew the answer would not need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR version

You need the syntax `git push hash:refs/heads/new-branch` so that their Git knows you want to create the new branch (on "their side", in *their* Git, it's an ordinary branch, after all).

#### Description

I think i know what you're trying to ask, but I'm not sure how you *should* have phrased the question.  (In particular, if you knew to ask about "refspecs", you could find the answer—but why would you know to ask about that?)

Let's try a rather different question, but for you to think about.  Suppose you created a *tag* `v0.9alpha`, and ran:

```
git push origin v0.9alpha
```

(as compared to the more typical `git push origin master` for instance).

How does Git know that you're pushing the *tag* and not some branch named `v0.9alpha`?  Remember, too, that with both `git push` and `git fetch`, there are *two* Gits involved, and *both* have to know and agree on this sort of thing.  It would be bad if your tag became a branch when you pushed it, or if you got tags from another Git but your Git created them locally as branches instead.

When you run `git branch` or `git tag` yourself, it's pretty obvious how your Git knows which one you mean: it's right there in the command.  But where is it in `git push` or `git fetch`?  It's not there ... or is it?

#### References have full names

The general form of these things—these human-readable names, these branches, tags, and any other name you can use to refer to some commit or whatever—is called a *reference* and references have "full names".  The full name of any branch starts with `refs/heads/`, so that `master` is really `refs/heads/master`.  The full name of any tag starts with `refs/tags/`.  The full name of any remote-tracking branch starts with `refs/remotes/`; the ones for `origin` in particular start with `refs/remotes/origin/`.

Git simply *shortens* the full names most of the time.  You type in `master`, not `refs/heads/master`, and Git figures out that you mean your *branch* `master`.  You type in `v0.9alpha`, and Git figures out that you mean your tag.  You type in `origin/master` and Git figures that one out too.

#### Push and fetch use refspecs

You already know that you can write `git push origin localBranch:newRemoteBranch`.  Git calls this thing—this `src:dst` pair—a *refspec*.  Each half of this is actually a reference, and that's the key to the whole puzzle.

(A refspec also has an optional leading plus sign.  If it's there, it means `--force`, but just for this one instance of a push or fetch, rather than for every pair.  Using `--force` with `git push` or `git fetch` means "set the force flag on every refspec".  The force flag is mainly meaningful for branch names, although it does get applied to other references too.)

If you just write:

```
git push origin xyz
```

your Git will look in *your* repository for some reference ending in `xyz`.  (The complete search is described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html); it's a six-step process.)  That search, and its result, tells Git what *kind* of reference `xyz` is—probably a branch, but maybe a tag.  As a result, your own Git knows, now, whether you meant `refs/heads/xyz` or `refs/tags/xyz`.

Your Git then uses the *same* full name when talking to the other Git, and that makes the other Git create or update the same *kind* of reference.

But when you write:

```
git push origin 91cb035:xyz
```

instead, your Git *doesn't* go through a six-step process to look up the hash `91cb035`.  So it *doesn't* know what kind of reference it should send to the other Git, yet.  Instead, it takes your weakly-specified `xyz`, and uses what the *other* Git has to try to guess whether you meant `refs/heads/xyz` or `refs/tags/xyz`, or perhaps some other `xyz` entirely.

If your Git can't guess and their Git can't help, because neither has an `xyz`, there's only one right answer: your Git can make *you* provide the full name.  You can run:

```
git push origin 91cb035:refs/heads/xyz
```

and your Git will now know it should send the other Git the full name `refs/heads/xyz`.  Their Git will treat that as a branch name, because that's what it *is*.

Comment: Very detailed explanation, appreciated! I did understand that short branch and tag names are basically aliases for a fully qualified reference, but still could not figure out the ref I needed. Was close though... I tried for dst `res/remote/origin/xyz` and that didn't work as expected. refs/heads/xyz does the trick indeed.